# How to mock window.gapi.load() React + Jest

Tags: reactjs, google-api, jestjs, enzyme, google-api-js-client

There's a question that answers this for Angular, and a question without any answers for Vuejs. I'm trying to find a way to mock the `window.gapi.load()` function in my tests. I'm new to React testing and this is what I have so far:

```js
it('should render the App component without crashing', function () {
  const component = renderer.create(
    shallow(
      <Root>
        <App/>
      </Root>
    )
  )

  let tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

I have tried a basic beforeEach call to try and load it or something but that didn't work either. Here is the code in the component:

```js
const App = () => {
  const { isSignedIn } = useSelector(state => state.auth)

  const renderApp = () => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      return <Home/>
    } else {
      return (
          <div className='app'>
            <h1 id='logo'>netTube</h1>
            <GoogleAuth/>
          </div>
      )
    }
  }

  return (
      <>
        { renderApp() }
      </>
  )
}
```

And the call in the GoogleAuth component:

```js
// GoogleAuth.jsx

componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
      window.gapi.client.init({
        clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: 'email'
      }).then(() => {
        this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        this.onAuthChange(this.auth.isSignedIn.get())
        this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(this.onAuthChange)
      })
    })
  }
```

If there is anything else you'd like me to add, please ask. Sorry if there is not enough information, as I said, I am super new to React testing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a little on the answers from Tom & Hector, I added a JWT token and it seems to work in Jest for mocking the basics of signing in & out of gapi.auth2:

```
window.gapi = {auth2: {}, client: {}};
window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance = () => {return new function() {
  this.isSignedIn = new function() {
    this.signedIn = false;
    this.get = () => this.signedIn;
    this.listen = (f) => f();
  };
  this.signIn = () => Promise.resolve(this.isSignedIn.signedIn = true);
  this.signOut = () => Promise.resolve(this.isSignedIn.signedIn = false);
  this.currentUser = new function() {
    this.get = () => new function() {
      this.getId = () => "XYZ";
      this.getAuthResponse = () => new function() {
        this.id_token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";
      };
      this.getBasicProfile = () => new function() {
        this.getName = () => "Mr Test";
        this.getEmail = () => "test@email.com";
        this.getImageUrl = () => "http://email.com/image";
      };
    };
  };
};}
window.gapi.auth2.init = () => {return Promise.resolve({});}
window.gapi.client.init = (v) => true;
window.gapi.load = (a, f) => f();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just mock each of the gapi call your components use. (Although with shallow rendering, your `componentDidMount` might not run.)

something like:

```
window.gapi = {};
window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance = () => {isSignedIn : {get : () => true, listen : f => f()}};
window.gapi.client.init = (v) => true;
window.gapi.load = (a, f) => f();
```

as the first lines of your `it` (or even better in before/beforeEach func)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I mocked my data in Jest for window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance . You could do the same.

example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from "../routes/Home";

let container = null;
beforeEach(() => {
    // setup a DOM element as a render target

    let profileObj = {
        getEmail: () => 'testUser@gmail.edu',
        getImageUrl: () => 'www.example.com/stem.jpg',
        getName : () => 'NON STEM user'
    }

    let getBasicProfileFun = { getBasicProfile: () => profileObj }

    let authInstanceObj = { 'currentUser': { get: () => getBasicProfileFun } }
    window.gapi = { 'auth2': "d" };
    window.gapi.auth2 = { getAuthInstance: () => authInstanceObj }

    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    // cleanup on exiting
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
});

it("renders with or without a name", () => {
    act(() => {
        render(<BrowserRouter><Home /></BrowserRouter>, container);
    });
    // console.log(container)
    expect(container.textContent).toBe(' PairStudytestUser@gmail.eduWelcome to Pair StudySelect your field of study and join a roomStemNon-StemJoin Room');
});
```